# Save information after click button in login with HTML5

Tags: html

I'm trying to get the user and password login after click login button.
I'm new in HTML.

As you can see, I add a function when I click the login button but I don't know how can I save this information in a txt file and redirect to a new url.

My new url is `file:///C:/Users/martin/Desktop/html_app/martin.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Overpass+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="main-content">
      <div class="header">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/zqpwkLQ.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="l-part">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="input-1" id="user" />
        <div class="overlap-text">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="input-2" id="passwd" />
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Log in" class="btn" onclick="var result = user_info();alert(result);" />
        <script>
          function user_info() {
            var user_name = document.getElementById("user").value;
            var passwd = document.getElementById("passwd").value;
            return user_name, passwd;
          }
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'd need a server side script, in a language like PHP, in order to save the form to a file.

Comment: As the comment above mentioned, You will need a server side language such as PHP to accomplish this. For security reasons, it can no longer be done with jQuery / Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As above mention comments , but i suppose your on learning stage so if you want to save it info you can use local Storage for this purpose with using JavaScript on  click you have save on local storage like localStorage.setItem("Forminfo", "{// all info of the form}");